# IIS 7.5 URL Redirect for specific patterns

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

When user enters domain.com it should redirect to my application which is https://www.domain.com. Currently it is not happening and it is showing a page "This Connection is Untrusted."

I have following rewrite tag added in my web.config:

```
        <rewrite>
           <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Currently in my IIS 7.5 i have added Inbound Rule which i have settings as follows:

1. In Match URL

   Requested URL: Matches the Pattern

   Using: Reqular Expression

   Pattern: (.*)

   Ignore Case: Checked
2. Conditions

   Logical Grouping: Match All

   Input: {HTTPS}

   Type: Matches the Pattern

   Pattern: ^OFF$

   Track group across condition: unchecked
3. Action

   Action Type: Redirect

   Redirect URL: https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}

   Append Query string: checked

   Redirect Type: See Other (303)

Please let me know if any changes can be made to existing settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i enter URL as www.domain.com it works fine, as it redirects properly to https://www.domain.com. But if i enter URL as domain.com it would show me error page as "The Connection is untrusted". this is because iam using https.

Answer (score 4):

Your rewrite rule is just redirecting to the same domain. So if a user enters just `domain.com` (defaulting to http) it will redirect to `https://domain.com`. If your SSL certificate does not contain `domain.com` but only `www.domain.com` it will cause the browser to prompt a warning about a wrong certificate. Though most certificate authorities nowadays issue certificates with both the domain with and without www (but maybe yours not).

If you want the user to always use `https://www.domain.com` (always with www) you should use the following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

It will force SSL and will force `www.domain.com` as a host header. If not, it will issue a permanent redirect (= beter) to the same URL.