# How to get a URL Rewrite for HTTP to HTTP AND non WWW to WWW to work

Tags: https, url-rewriting, seo, iis-8, isapi-rewrite

I have been over the web hunting for solutions for this, but I can get only 1 and 2 to work.

1. `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
2. `www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
3. `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
4. `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
5. `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`
6. `example.com/page.aspx` to `https://www.example.com/page.aspx`

Requirements:

- All URLs to be HTTPS
- All URLs without WWW in them to show WWW
- All other redirects to work, query strings and params carried over etc.

So the main issue is that if no protocol is specified (`http` or `https`) then if I enter `example.com/blah` then it gets converted to `www.example.com/blah` but put a protocol (`http` or `https`) in front and it breaks the link.

As I don't currently have a rule to move non-WWW URLs to WWW, then I am not sure what is doing it, if I have to do it, how I can get it to work with HTTP to HTTPS.

- I have tried putting the rules for HTTP to go to HTTPS together with a rule for non-WWW to WWW but it didn't work (first example you will see - bottom example is what I am using at the moment).
- I have tried using `{HTTP_HOST}` instead of writing out my site's URL in the redirect part of the rule.
- I have tried splitting the rules into 2, one for HTTP to HTTPS, and one for no-WWW to WWW.

However nothing seems to work.

At the moment I am just using my hosts file and practising, changing the rules in the web.config file for the site on Win 2012 box.

I have other rules as well e.g for `www.example.com/plugins` to go to the page (rewrite) underneath `.aspx`, but these don't work either if there is no `www` in the URL.

So it seems the redirection of non-WWW URLs to WWW is the issue and I don't know the best way to combine it with the HTTP to HTTPS rules.

I was trying a combo of the two rules which covers the HTTPS/WWW and works apart from no 4/5 (non-WWW to WWW) this is that rule.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
             </rule>
```

The actual switching of `logicalGrouping="MatchAny"` to `"MatchAll"` doesn't seem to make a difference by the way.

As long as someone doesn't type the URL as `http://example.com/plugins` then it works fine and is redirected to `https://www.example.com/plugins`.

Not that I know many people who actually type the protocol in when entering links now (`//` works as well) but it's obviously the old search engines, and site embedded links I need to handle for duplicate content.

Can anyone think of a reason why this isn't working OR what I should try?

I have bindings set up for both port 80/443 for WWW and without.

I never find in answers to problems like these that people talk much about the IIS settings such as bindings and ports but I think they should as web.config is tied into the URL Redirect application and bindings are obviously required for your addresses.

I just find it weird that the example rule I put up earlier works just as well as this one which only mentions HTTP to HTTPS.

This is what I am currently using. Maybe IIS does something with `www`?

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
             </rule>
```

I even changed the order of the bindings so that non-WWW bindings went before the WWW bindings thinking that might have something to do with it.

I control my DNS and my A record is set like

```
DNSEntry - WWW
Type - A
Destination - MY IP
```

So I am a bit confused to what is actually forcing non-WWW URLs to go to WWW URLs. As the command I am currently using in web.config only mentions HTTPS.

I am thinking maybe there is something in IIS (I am not an IIS 8 expert) that has set something to do it or the setting of one of the values should have been a domain without WWW in it.

Any help would be much appreciated. I doubt there are many URLs about pointing to my site without the WWW in it anyway but it would be good to know for SEO that I could force them all to one place so I don't get caught on duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

[How to force HTTPS using a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file)

[IIS 7.5 URL Redirect for specific patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428357/iis-7-5-url-redirect-for-specific-patterns)

[Override an IIS rewrite rule for child site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851032/override-an-iis-rewrite-rule-for-child-site)